# Searchbar not reloading to original data after search result using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uisearchbar

My scenario, I implemented codebase for `UISearchbar` with some `animation` effect like `expand` and `collapse`.

Here, whenever I am trying to `search` the search result displaying well after I added custom clear `button` it will `operate` collapse animation same time `reload` search result to `original` table `data`.

My issues is whenever I am clicking the custom clear button `search` result not reloading to `original` data in `tableview`.

```
func didTapFavoritesBarButtonOFF() {

        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([self.favoritesBarButtonOn], animated: false)
        print("Hide Searchbar")

        // Reload tableview 
        searchBar.text = nil
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
        filteredData.removeAll()
        self.tableView.reloadData() // not working

        // Dismiss keyboard
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

        // Enable navigation left bar buttons
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false

        let isOpen = leftConstraint.isActive == true

        // Inactivating the left constraint closes the expandable header.
        leftConstraint.isActive = isOpen ? false : true

        // Animate change to visible.
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.navigationItem.titleView?.alpha = isOpen ? 0 : 1
            self.navigationItem.titleView?.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
```

My Tableview cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredData.count
 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.titleLabel.text = self.filteredData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: please show implementation of `cellForRowAt:` method

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer.@– Mahendra GP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set data source array to original one.

**Reason**

Actually you are removing the datasource array `filteredData.removeAll()`. After this an array is empty that is the reason `self.tableView.reloadData()` is not working.

**Solution**

You need to make a copy of data source array, lets say `originalData` contains the original data (without filter).

Whenever you user filter then you need to use `originalData` to filter the data.

For Eg.

```
let filterdData = originalData.filter { //filter data }
```

So when you clear filter you need to set the original data again to table data source array.

For Eg.

```
filteredData.removeAll() //remove all data
filterData = originalData //Some thing that you need to assign for table data source
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

In table's `cellForRowAt:` will get the data as follow...

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      var obj = filterData[indexPath.row] 
      print(obj)

 }
```

**Don't forget to assign data to `originalData` before filter**

Comment: great help. I really appreciate your valuable answer and the way of explanation excellent ...good job man thank you!